# Alerting users with a pop-up window

Tags: python, beginner, performance

I'm relatively new at programming in general including Python. But I've tried to create a program in Python that alerts users through a pop up window to perform an action every 2 hours.

```
import time
import ctypes

count = 0

print "This break message was sent on "+time.ctime()
messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextAskingToDoSomething", "WindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x4)
if returnValue == 6:
    messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
    returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextRespondingToAnswerYes", "SWindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x0)
elif returnValue == 7:
    messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
    returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextRespondingToAnswerNo", "WindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x0)

while (count < 4):
    time.sleep(60*60*2)
    print "This break message was sent on"+time.ctime()
    messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
    returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextAskingToDoSomething", "WindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x4)
    if returnValue == 6:
        messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
        returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextRespondingToAnswerYes", "WindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x0)
    elif returnValue == 7:
        messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
        returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextRespondingToAnswerNo", "WindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x0)
    count = count + 1

time.localtime()
```

It essentially calls a message box with a title and a text in it and if the user clicks one button then another one follow up message box appears. If the user clicks on the other button, then another follow up message appears. This process is repeated every 2 hours for 5 times.

How could I improve this code to be shortened? Could I use a function somehow? Or what would be a way to shorten it and avoid me repeating myself too much (if that is the case)?

Comment: I didn't notice it on your SO question, but are you really giving the same message in every case?

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Also what's the point of  `returnValue = messageBox(None, "Text", "Title", 0x40 | 0x0)` inside of those `if` conditions(in `while` loop) if you're actually ignoring them when the while loop restarts?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - thanks for the indentation tip. The first block of code calls the pop up window as soon as someone runs the program. Then, everything after the while loop runs every 2 hours for 5 times. Does this help clarify?

Comment: @RubberDuck - Yes I've also edited the texts in the code above to try to illustrate. But if you click in the button Yes then it shows one message as follow up if you click No, then it shows another message as follow up. After 2hrs, it repeats the process...

Comment: I was talking about the `returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextRespondingToAnswerNo", "WindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x0)` inside of the while loop, you're not using these `returnValue` anywhere. So, are those `returnValue` actually required? Currently you're re-calculating `returnValue = messageBox(None, "TextAskingToDoSomething", "WindowTitle", 0x40 | 0x4)` every time the `while` loop re-starts.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Once a user clicks the TextRespondingToAnswerNo button, the window output displays the message. I think waht you're saying is that I didn't have to have a returnValue object since I'm not using anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

You could change `count = count + 1` to `count += 1` besides that, do you need to repeat `messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA` so much? If it doesn't change, couldn't you just have it once? You could also add variables to shorten repeated lines like making a variable called `resetMsgBox` and have it be: `resetMsgBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA` so it's easier to read by having `messageBox = resetMsgBox` every line instead, I suppose.